# Iterating a JSON to get certain elements and use them afterwards

Tags: python, json

I'm hitting an API endpoint which returns me a JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 68663,
        "login": "test1",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 67344,
        "login": "test2",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 66095,
        "login": "hi",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 63529,
        "login": "another_one",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 63278,
        "login": "soforth",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 63277,
        "login": "rahok",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is get every login value so I can use it to send it in another request (to get more information about the said user)

I have tried following some of the previous answers, but it kept throwing different errors, my current last code is like this:

```
data = get_req("/v2/users/")
for login in data:
    print (data)
    for attr, value in login.items():
        print (attr, value)
return login
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `data` a `str`, or is it the `list` decoded from a JSON value?

Comment: If it is already a list, `return login` is just going to return the last  `dict` in the list. Do you want to return a list of some kind?

Comment: Could you give the error message? Even it you cannot fully understand it, it could help other readers...

Comment: @chepner Sorry, running `type(data)` says it's `str`

Comment: Then you need to decode it first: `data = json.loads(data)`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked in conjugation with the answer below.  @chepner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code piece would print each login value from dictionary...

```
>>> data = [
    {
        "id": 68663,
        "login": "test1",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 67344,
        "login": "test2",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 66095,
        "login": "hi",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 63529,
        "login": "another_one",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 63278,
        "login": "soforth",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 63277,
        "login": "rahok",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    }
]
>>> for d in data:
        login_value = d['login']
        print(login_value)
        # do something with login value


test1
test2
hi
another_one
soforth
rahok
```

Comment: I just tried this, but I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Comment: are you indexing the list or dict.

Comment: Hey, this worked, thanks. I just needed to follow on @chepner comment and put `json.loads` on data, since it was `str`.

Answer (score 0):

.items() returns an array of tuples

```
for i in login.items():
    print(i[0], i[1])
```